# Adding calculation in where condition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following code

```
Select MR.MRPRoductId,MR.PartNo, E.MaterialName as Producttomake,EP.MaterialName as NeededProduct,(MR.ApprovedQty*PCM.NeededQuantity-isnull(SUM(ISS.IssuedQty),0))as Needed,PCM.NeededProductPartNo,
EP.UOM,ISNULL(SM.Quantity,0)as Available from Material_Requisition MR 
join Productconversion_master PCM on MR.PartNo=PCM.ConvertedProductPartNo 
Left join ProductConversion_IssueSlip ISS on PCM.NeededProductPartNo=ISS.IssuedPartNo
join ElectricalProducts E on MR.PartNo=E.PartNo join ElectricalProducts EP on PCM.NeededProductPartNo=EP.PartNo 
Left join StockMaster SM  on PCM.NeededProductPartNo=SM.PartNo and SM.LocationId='LOC_001' where MR.MRID='TFIPL/MR/CON/NR/2013-14/00001' 
 group by EP.MaterialName,MR.MRPRoductId,MR.PartNo,E.MaterialName,
MR.ApprovedQty,PCM.NeededQuantity,PCM.NeededProductPartNo,EP.UOM,SM.Quantity
```

the result of this query as follows

[image: Result]

i want to select only Needed>0 .how to add it in where condition

Answer (score 1):

Two options.

**Option 1** - simplest in my opinion

```
SELECT list
     , of
     , columns
FROM   (
        <your query goes here>
       ) As a_subquery
WHERE  needed > 0
```

**Option 2**

```
<your_query goes here>
HAVING (MR.ApprovedQty*PCM.NeededQuantity-isnull(SUM(ISS.IssuedQty),0)) > 0
```

You can't use a `WHERE` condition in this scenario because it is applying to an aggregate. The equivalent to this for aggregates is the `HAVING` clause (which is placed *after* `GROUP BY`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr.gvee , can you give a simple example for the option 2 because i have to pass LocationId and MRID in where condition

Comment: @Guna Option 2 really is as simple as it shows. I would copy your exact query from your question and add the additional line. That's it! You can still add a WHERE clause in the normal manner (before the group-by) if required.

Comment: @Guna essentially; if it contains an aggregate function (in this example; `SUM()`) then it should go in the HAVING clause, otherwise use the WHERE clause as normal.